# SOAP UI - <xs:choice> and <xs:element> as siblings under <xs:sequence> not interpreted correctly

Tags: xsd, soapui

I am using SOAPUI for sending SOAP requests to my web service.

When I have `<xs:choice>` and `<xs:element>` as siblings under `<xs:sequence>`, the choice element does not appear as a combo box, instead appears as sequence of elements.

In this case, my SOAP request in SOAPUI shows all the elements ignoring `<xs:choice>`.

Please let me know if somebody ran into this problem and got any solution

Comment: "combo box"? I do not understand. A SOAP message is normally just XML.

Comment: When you have a xs:choice in your SOAP message, the form tab in SOAP UI shows a combo box, which lets you select one element among the choice of elements defined

Comment: I have never seen that. For me, it has always been `<option>` elements that created the combo box.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand you are looking for is numerated list

Like this

```
        <xs:simpleType name="regularType">
          <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:enumeration value="yes"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="no"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
```

and add as many choices as you need.

Edit: I know it's 4 months old question, but I guess someone in the future might benefit from this.